# exist.db Error during trigger prepare

Tags: triggers, locking, exist-db

If I'm trying to modify or even create a file in a project folder inside my exist-db (Version 3.4.1) the following error appears.

*Message:*

```
XMLDBException: Failed to invoke method parse in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: 
org.exist.collections.triggers.TriggerException: Error during trigger prepare
org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XQST0048 It is a static error if a 
function or variable declared in a library module is not in the target namespace of the 
library module. [source: /db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql]
```

*Exception Stacktrace:*

```
org.xmldb.api.base.XMLDBException: Failed to invoke method parse in class 
org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: 
org.exist.collections.triggers.TriggerException: Error during trigger prepare
org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XQST0048 It is a static error if a function or variable declared in a library module is not in the target namespace of the library module. [source: /db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql]
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.store(RemoteCollection.java:528)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.storeResource(RemoteCollection.java:502)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.storeResource(RemoteCollection.java:471)
at org.exist.client.DocumentView$2.run(DocumentView.java:361)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to invoke method parse in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: 
org.exist.collections.triggers.TriggerException: Error during trigger prepare
org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XQST0048 It is a static error if a function or variable declared in a library module is not in the target namespace of the library module. [source: /db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql]
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.store(RemoteCollection.java:524)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to invoke method parse in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: 
org.exist.collections.triggers.TriggerException: Error during trigger prepare
org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XQST0048 It is a static error if a function or variable declared in a library module is not in the target namespace of the library module. [source: /db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql]
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.store(RemoteCollection.java:524)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.storeResource(RemoteCollection.java:502)
at org.exist.xmldb.RemoteCollection.storeResource(RemoteCollection.java:471)
at org.exist.client.DocumentView$2.run(DocumentView.java:361)
```

Maybe a locking problem? In another folder in the same project all ressources can be edited. And the files where the error appears were initially created by me... so it worked before already.

After a fresh install it works for a while and then suddenly the error appears again.

The permissions are set correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe explanation for your problem is in this part of the error message:

```
err:XQST0048 It is a static error if a function or variable declared in a library module is not in the target namespace of the library module. [source: /db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql]
```

The trigger on your collection contains an error, so when it fires and you are trying to store a document, the error caused by the trigger prevents the document from being stored.

You need to edit `/db/apps/ediarum/routinen/trigger/set-permissions-for-document.xql` and fix the error in your XQuery.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. Didn't read that path in detail... Finally it's a problem with the special verision (3.4.1) of eXist-db and the tool "ediarum".